# Assigning line in file to print

Tags: python-3.x

So after I have a file opened, the following code is suppose to read through the lines and only print lines that contain the year that I input and the income code that I input, however for income I have to enter a number 1-4 that represent a line in the word file, how can i write it so that the number recognizes the word

```
input_year = input("Enter a year:")
print()

print("Choose one of the following:")
print("1 for low income.")
print("2 for lower middle income.")
print("3 for upper middle income.")
print("4 for high income.")
print()     

income_code_input = input("Enter income level:")


for line in input_file:
   line = line.strip()
   country = line[0:50]
   income = line[51:56]
   vaccination = line[59:60]
   region = line[62:83]
   year = line[-4:]

   if year.startswith(input_year) and income.startswith(income_code_input):
      print(line.rstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

The data format is not specified so I can only guess at what the income field starts with.  This is my guess:

```
code = {'1':'low ', '2':'lower', '3':'upper', '4':'high'}
if year.startswith(input_year) and income.startswith(code[income_code_input]):
    print(line.rstrip())
```

The above uses a dictionary, `code`, to translate from the number that the user entered to a string that the income field starts with.  Note that
 `input` returns a string so that the keys in the `code` dictionary are all strings, e.g. `'1'`, not numbers, e.g. `1`.  Note also that we need to distinguish between 'low' and 'lower'.  Consequently, I kept a trailing space after 'low' in the value for `code[1]`.